# Set cookie on the header of a POST request using angular4 service

Tags: angular, http, cookies

I would like to pass some cookies through the HTTP POST requests header using angular4. Here I am calling an external API and trying to pass this particular cookie. I've googled but I do not yet get any correct solution. Please help me for the same. The following are the codes I've tried.

```
public getTransactionStatus(transactionID: string): Promise<any> {
    let header = new Headers;
    let body = { "transactionID": "123" };
    header.append('content-type', 'application/json');
    header.append('set-cookie', 'test=hi; FedAuth=sadsa54ea4da5');
    return this.http.post(uri, body, { headers: header })
      .toPromise()
      .then((res) => {
        let temp = res.json();
        return { 'statusCode': 200, 'message': 'success', 'result': temp, 'error': {} };
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        return { 'statusCode': 200, 'message': 'failed', 'result': {}, 'error': error };
      });
  }
```

Comment: Did you try `withCredentials:true`?

Comment: @AnshumanJaiswal I just tried like header.append('withCredentials','true'). Is it the correct way of implementation

Comment: Please, use httpClient (not the old and deprecated http) see https://angular.io/guide/http#httpclient. The headers must be add like show in https://angular.io/guide/http#adding-headers